# newlines in double quotes in reading CSV in python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a csv file in the following format:

```
"4931286","Lotion","New York","Bright color, yellow with 5" long
20% nylon"
"931286","Shampoo","New York","Dark, yellow with 10" long
20% nylon"
"3931286","Conditioner","LA","Bright color, yellow with 5" long
50% nylon"
```

The above data should be read as 3 rows with 4 columns: ID, product name, location, and description. As can be seen, there are newlines within descriptions for each row.

I've been searching other related stackoverflow questions but none of the solutions seem to solve this issue.

Here is my attempt:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
file = StringIO("""4931286","Lotion","New York","Bright color, yellow\n   with 5" long 20% nylon""")

for row in csv.reader(file,quotechar='"', delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True):
 print row
```

And the results look the following:

```
['4931286"', 'Lotion', 'New York', 'Bright color, yellow with 5 long']
   ['20% nylon']
```

But, what I want is

```
['4931286"', 'Lotion', 'New York', 'Bright color, yellow with 5 long 20% nylon']
```

How could I achieve this? There should be a way in python?

Comment: I I may, either you have a properly formatted CSV file and you parse it as such, or you are trying to hack it in and you should write a different parsing function for your specific case.

Comment: How is pandas relevant? Is your data coming from pandas? If so, I'm surprised, because I agree with the others who have said your CSV isn't valid. I wouldn't expect pandas to produce data like what you have. I don't think you will find any combination of dialect settings in the built-in `csv` module to handle your data exactly as it is.

Comment: Ah, sorry for the confusion. The data is from sql database using SQL Workbench. I included pandas tag just in case there might be a way in pandas' pandas.read_csv function may be able to solve it.

Answer (score 4):

The data is not in CSV format.

`"` in CSV  must be escaped with `\` like `"Bright color, yellow\n   with 5\" long 20% nylon"`.

If `"` is only used for inches (prefixed with number) try this:

```
import re
data = re.sub(r'([0-9])"(?![,\n])', r'\1\\"', data)
```

This regex will replace all `"` with `\"` if it is prefixed by a number

and then parse the data with `csv.reader`

Edit: Changed regex because of [MaxU's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37794283/newlines-in-double-quotes-in-reading-csv-in-python/37794694?noredirect=1#comment63058916_37794694).

Comment: I think you should also make sure that you won't escape strings like this: `"Column 1", "Column 2"`, I.e. if there is `[,\n]` after the `"` then it shouldn't be escaped

Comment: @user4279562 You're welcome. Please consider accepting the answer if the answer helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

How about iterating over every two lines,

```
import csv
from StringIO import StringIO
from itertools import izip

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0, s1), (s2, s3), (s4, s5), ..."
    a = iter(iterable)
    return izip(a, a)


file = StringIO(""""4931286","Lotion","New York","Bright color, yellow with 5" long
20% nylon"
"931286","Shampoo","New York","Dark, yellow with 10" long
20% nylon"
"3931286","Conditioner","LA","Bright color, yellow with 5" long
50% nylon"
""")

reader = csv.reader(file,quotechar='"', delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True)
for row, row2 in pairwise(reader):
    row[-1] = ' '.join([row[-1], row2[0]])
    print(row)

# Output
['4931286', 'Lotion', 'New York', 'Bright color, yellow with 5 long 20% nylon"']
['931286', 'Shampoo', 'New York', 'Dark, yellow with 10 long 20% nylon"']
['3931286', 'Conditioner', 'LA', 'Bright color, yellow with 5 long 50% nylon"']
```

Comment: That is not a robust solution - in case there is another newline the function would break. It could work for the scenario and example data in the question though.